How do I prove pseudo-associativity of generalized composition in Agda?
I've been trying to translate the paper "Continuation-Passing Style, Defunctionalization, Accumulations, and Associativity" available here: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2111/2111.10413.pdf from Idris to Agda.
The final example discusses generalized composition, which appears to be equivalent to the mapₙ function in Function.Nary.NonDependent.Base, and proves that it is pseudo-associative. I have been struggling to get this to typecheck in Agda. What I would like is a type like below:
mapₙ-assoc : ∀ {n m : ℕ} {ls ls′ r s t} {x : Set r} {y : Set s} {z : Set t} {as : Sets n ls} {bs : Sets m ls′}
  → (h : y → z) → (g : Arrows (suc m) (x , bs) y) → (f : Arrows n as x)
  → mapₙ n (mapₙ (suc m) h g) f ≡ mapₙ (n + m) h (mapₙ n g f)

But this does not type check with the error:
n != n + m of type ℕ
when checking that the expression mapₙ n g f has type _as_1119 ⇉ y

I have tried making the below version, but I can't figure out how to make the induction step work or even if it could work like this.
mapₙ-assoc : ∀ {n m : ℕ} {ls ls′ r s t} {x : Set r} {y : Set s} {z : Set t} {as : Sets n ls} {bs : Sets m ls′}
  → (h : y → z) → (g : Arrows (suc m) (x , bs) y) → (f : Arrows n as x) → Set _
mapₙ-assoc {zero} {m} h g f = mapₙ zero (mapₙ (suc m) h g) f ≡ mapₙ (zero + m) h (mapₙ zero g f)
mapₙ-assoc {suc n} {m} h g f = {!!}

This version works for any specific n that I've tried, not just zero, so I assume Agda can expand to see the types are equal, but I can't convince it that they are with a general n.

The problem is that mapₙ n g f has type Arrows n as (Arrows m bs y), not Arrows (n + m) (as ++ bs) y. You can prove these equivalent and convert between them (you'll have to define _++_ for Levels and Sets first), or you could just use mapₙ n (mapₙ m h) instead of mapₙ (n + m) h.
mapₙ-assoc : ∀ {n m : ℕ} {ls ls′ r s t} {x : Set r} {y : Set s} {z : Set t} {as : Sets n ls} {bs : Sets m ls′}
  → (h : y → z) → (g : Arrows (suc m) (x , bs) y) → (f : Arrows n as x)
  → mapₙ n (mapₙ (suc m) h g) f ≡ mapₙ n (mapₙ m h) (mapₙ n g f)


I had already created the equality between Arrows n as (Arrows m bs y) and Arrows (n + m) (as ++ bs) y, as well as the requisite _++_ for Levels and Sets, but neglected to mention it in my question, my bad. I still couldn't figure out how to use that in the type of mapₙ-assoc to get it to work. How would I go about using that equality to get the original version to typecheck?

Well you can just transport mapₙ n g f along that equality with subst (λ x → x) before applying mapₙ (n + m) h.

Ah, got it. I had applied subst on the left hand side, but needed it on both sides of the _≡_. Thanks!

You could do it on one side by converting mapₙ (n + m) h from a function ((as ++ bs) ⇉ y) → (as ++ bs) ⇉ z to a function (as ⇉ bs ⇉ y) → as ⇉ bs ⇉ z, using your equality twice. By the way, how did you prove that equality? You have to prove that the levels on both sides are equal first, right, in other words that ⨆ n as ⊔ ⨆ m bs ≡ ⨆ (n + m) (as ++ˡ bs)?

So I was able to prove the equality on Levels that you mention: (⨆ n ℓs) ⊔ (⨆ m ℓs′) ≡ ⨆ (n + m) (ℓs ++ᴸ ℓs′), but I couldn't get it to typecheck on the Set level, i.e. Set (r ⊔ ((⨆ n ℓs) ⊔ (⨆ m ℓs′))) ≡ Set (r ⊔ (⨆ (n + m) (ℓs ++ᴸ ℓs′))). I realized that I had accidentally left on --type-in-type so it glossed over this before. Any ideas on how to get that working? I don't think we can transport at the Set level anymore, can we?

Honestly I would not bother trying to prove an equality if an equivalence/isomorphism does the trick.

Fair enough, equivalence is definitely sufficient. Thanks again for all the help!
